# Using node.js to execute 'tracert' in cmd, but my output is not consistent

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a node.js script that executes tracert in cmd, and I would like to parse the output of tracert to be able to use in node. My issue is that the output I am receiving is not coming in consistently.

```js
let argument = process.argv[2] /* what the user enters as first argument */

const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const command = spawn(process.env.comspec, ['/c', 'tracert', argument])

command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

tracert outputs in this format on each line, for each hop.

```
1    5 ms     6 ms     4 ms     192.168.1.1
```

The expected output of the console.log SHOULD be:

```
stdout: 1
stdout: 5 ms
stdout: 6 ms
stdout: 4 ms
stdout: 192.168.1.1
```

and indeed that is what happens about 90% of the time, but sometimes the data comes in so fast, that some lines come together on the same line like so

```
stdout: 1
stdout: 5 ms
stdout: 6 ms 4 ms
stdout: 192.168.1.1
```

I don't want this to happen. I want each time the data variable comes in, that it only contains "one element" from each "column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't force `tracert` to send data column by column. Moreover, you cannot force OS, not to "join" columns in buffer when your process is not fast enough to read them from pipe.

The only possible solution is to wait until whole line is ready and only then parse it. Stg like this (warning, this is only pseudocode).

```
let bufffer = "";
command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    buffer = buffer + data;
    while (buffer.indexOf('\n') != -1) { // loop because in some cases you can even receive many lines
         const idx = buffer.indexOf('\n');
         const line = buffer.substr(0, idx).trim(); // get line and trim extra whitespace
         buffer = buffer.substr(idx+1); // rest of buffer, usually empty string

         // now parse line with regexp or something
         const match = /(\d+) (\d+) ms +(\d+) ms +(\d+) ms ([^ ]+)/.match(line);
         if (match) {
             ...
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Being able to receive line by line, makes it much simpler to parse. This works excellently for me.